# Desenvolvimento de jogos para celulares

Tags: java, sdk, java-8, java-me

É possível desenvolver jogos para celulares utilizando a nova SDK do Java ME (SDK 8)? Ou seja, consigo fazer projetos no qual aparece um emulador do celular e desenvolver para ele?

Estou meio confuso quanto a isso. Sei que tem umas versões mais antigas, que usam o midp 2.0 com o wireless toolkit 2.5, por exemplo, mas não consegui e não sei se a nova sdk já engloba isso permitindo tal desenvolvimento.

Enfim, eu gostaria de saber qual a tecnologia Java ME mais nova para desenvolver graficamente (mais especificamente jogos) para celulares.

Comment: Para desenvolvimento de jogos eu recomendaria alguma engine, tipo a Unity 3D. Com elas você tem tudo mais facilitado e pode exportar seu jogo para várias plataformas.

Answer (score 3):

O SDK do Java ME 8 contém as APIs das versões anteriores (e as novidades das JSRS  CLDC 8 e MEEP 8), incluindo MIDLets. Para mais informações você pode ler:

- [A documentação para desenvolvedores do Java ME SDK 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/8.0/sdk-dev-guide/toc.htm)
- [A documentação do Netbeans sobre Java ME](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/dev_jme_apps.htm#BACDBIJJ)
- [A guia de uso da versão Embedded para Eclipse](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/rel/3.3/win/gs/html/getstart_win32/setup_eclipseenv.htm#Z8563WSD)
- [O guia de uso da versão Embedded para Netbeans](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/rel/3.3/win/gs/html/getstart_win32/setup_nbenv.htm#Z8983GHOT)

Além das APIs do Java ME, uma vasta gama de aparelhos suporta [JavaFX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/index.html) para interfaces ricas. Algumas fabricantes também desenvolvem APIs complementares ao Java ME para extrair o máximo dos seus aparelhos. Tenha em mente porém que o modelo de plataformas do Android e IOS mudou a cara do mercado *mobile* e hoje boa parte do esforço de desenvolvimento é voltado para as APIs nativas desses sistemas ao invés do Java ME.